# Can't use Coefficient properly

Tags: coefficients

I could successfully solve an ODE (Ordinary Differential Equation) with this:

```
Simplify[DSolve[C T'[t]+H T[t]==(Rcu I0^2 + 2Rcu r tau I0 + Rs r tau + H Ti) -2 r Rcu (I0 + r tau) t + R cu r^2 t^2,T[t],t]]
```

But I can't extract constant term out of the solution:

```
Coefficient[%,t]
```

What is wrong?

Correction: I missed 0 in the Coefficient

```
Coefficient[%,t,0]
```

Comment: `Coefficient[DSolveValue[C T'[t] + H T[t] == (Rcu I0^2 + 2 Rcu r tau I0 + Rs r tau + H Ti) - 2 r Rcu (I0 + r tau) t + R cu r^2 t^2, T[t], t][[1]], t, 0] // FullSimplify`

Comment: Thank you Bob. This worked.

Comment: if you want to notify others in the comments section, you should use the at option. For instance, @BobHanlon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I can't extract constant term

I do not know if I understood you right or not.

```
ode = C T'[t] + H T[t] == (Rcu I0^2 + 2 Rcu r tau I0 + Rs r tau + H Ti) - 
   2 r Rcu (I0 + r tau) t + R cu r^2 t^2
sol = DSolveValue[ode, T[t], t]
sol = Expand[sol]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

now to find terms with no $t$ in the solution (i.e. constant)

```
Cases[sol, x_ /; FreeQ[x, t]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can assemble it back using

```
 Plus @@ % // Simplify
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

To find terms that depends on $t$

```
Cases[sol, x_ /; Not@FreeQ[x, t]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Btw, you should not use `C` as symbol/variable as this is used by Mathematica itself.